# How to change a form controls using treeview in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, treeview

I'm using `C#`, and I want create a form - which is composed of `treeview` `treeview1`, a panel `panel1` and a button `btn1`.

In the begining the panel is empty, then a `userControl` `userControl1` will be shown when the user select a node from the tree, and another userControl `userControl2` will replace the first whene the user select another specific node , and go on ... as in setting forms

I found  a solution here :

[How to create an options form in C# Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166853/how-to-create-an-options-form-in-c-sharp-windows-forms)

but it is written i pseudo-code, i try implementing the code, and this what i get:

```
        //on initializing
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());

        treeView1.Nodes[0].Tag = new UserControl1();
        treeView1.Nodes[1].Tag = new UserControl2();
        treeView1.Nodes[2].Tag = new UserControl3();

        treeView1.Nodes[0].Text = "user controle1";
        treeView1.Nodes[1].Text = "user controle2";
        treeView1.Nodes[2].Text = "user controle3";

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
              UserControl currentControl = (UserControl)treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag;

               TreeNode currentnode = treeView1.SelectedNode;

        if (panel1.Controls != null)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
        }

        if (currentnode.Tag == null)
            return;

        panel1.Controls.Add((UserControl)currentnode.Tag);
    }
```

and about the usecontrols I add nothing to the code, just controls that i need...

It works, but I am not sure if it is correct, I find other solutions and they add a lot of stuff to both, the user controls and to the main form.

So, what this code need to work properly.

Comment: As usual, defining what is *correct* is improbable. If your implementation produces the expected results, it doesn't cause errors, it doesn't explode just because someone's using it, its design follows the general rules related to UI presentation and doesn't violate the *Principle of least astonishment*, it's probably *correct*. It's easier to spot design flows and/or code that might fail in some (or all) situations. For example, here you're checking: `if (currentnode.Tag == null)` when you have already cast it to `UserControl` (which is not used anymore). Btw, `e.Node` is the current Node.

Comment: As a suggestion, I wouldn't set a new instance of a UserControl to the Tag of each Node. You could just store the class Name and then use `Activator.CreateInstance("[Namespace.ClassName]")` to create an instance of your UserControls if/when required. Possibly, disposing of the instance when not used anymore. This, however, depends on the *weight* of the UserControls. (As a note, if you posted on SO the code that generates the Option Dialogs of the Visual Studio Options Tool, you'ld probably get downvoted. Hard.)

Comment: If you have only a limited number of UCs to show this may work fine. If the number is more dynamic you may create them in a more dynamic way. The real question is : what do they do and when will you need to refer back to them..??

Comment: Thank you very much guys, for your time and for your advices. And @Jimi, could you post a better code "that generates the Option Dialogs of the...", and as i said : i think that the code needs a LOT to be added... so could you help,please.

Comment: OK, I'll post an example.

Comment: @Jimi, ... :):)

Comment: Yep, sorry, got busy. I've already put together the example but I think it's a bit complicated. I'll post it anyway, give me some time to write it down.

Comment: @Jimi, ...'o_o'

Comment: I know, I know :) C'mon it's the weekend. Be patient :)

Comment: @Jimi, ... '( >_< )'